# As of April 2015, what is the oldest working version of skype, and where can it be downloaded?

Tags: skype

***Don't think this is an easy answer.*** Skype has been killing off old versions (such as the beloved 4.2.0.169 and 5.10.0.116) and forcing new versions. Most of the "old version" websites that used to host the old install files have completely stopped hosting Skype - my best guess is that Microsoft forced these sites to link to the newest version. Sites that no longer host the download files are:

- **FileHippo** (all the download links fail)
- **OldVersion** (download gets redirected to homepage)
- **Oldapps.com** (there is a notice at the top that Skype is not available anymore)
- **CNET** (download gets redirected to skype homepage)
- **Oldware.org** (all versions are 3.0 or less, and cannot sign in properly)
- **FileHorse.com** (download gets redirected to homepage)

I am looking for a working version of Skype 4 or 5... because 6 and 7 are atrocious. If anyone has an idea where to download the best, most bug-free working version, please let us know!

**UPDATE**: I found and tried various versions, 5 and below. I can confirm that all versions less than 6.0, and according to Alejandro below, *versions 6.6 and below will no longer work*. **I have successfully installed version 6.21.0.104 from [this reddit link](https://www.reddit.com/r/skype/comments/2o8gbp/how_to_undo_the_skype_update_and_go_back_to/coeulfw?context=1), the last version before the interface was completely botched**.

[image: Message received on Skype 5.10.0.116 and other old versions]

Comment: Mozilla's Firefox now includes Hello, which is a free voice-and-video-call system.  I have never tried it, but if it meets your needs, it could be a way to replace Skype for you.  It's completely free, to my knowledge.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard Mozilla I am not looking for alternatives to Skype; just trying to find the oldest skype version that works. So far I've found the one in the edited OP. Mozilla Hello doesn't support group calls (as of right now) which is a much used feature in Skype: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1050067

Comment: This might be a moving target, which makes it somewhat problematic. The most recent working version might get disabled 5 minutes after someone posts a question...

Comment: @degenerate From what I've read, you are correct about the current limitations of Hello.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my personal experience with it, I was forced to "update" from version 6.6 to the then latest 6.16 version which I'm right now at the time of this writing.

So it can be reasonably assumed that versions up to 6.6 are effectively dead and useless (including the 5.X and my personal favorite 3.X). 6.16 is working relatively fine right now for me at least, and I'm refusing to downgrade to 7.X for as long as possible (I also hate the new "everything is a tablet" design Microsoft is using all over). So the absolute oldest version right now should be something between 6.6 and 6.16.

The only flaw I got with my current version is receiving images from the newer 7.X clients. The new behavior of those when sending images is, instead of just delivering the image client-to-client, it uploads and published to the Microsoft website, then sends a link to the other person. [6.X clients receiving that will only see the link](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA34458/why-don-t-i-see-the-picture-my-contact-sent-me). 7.X clients actually download the image and render it within the chat, but the file is still published and accessible to anyone capable of guessing the link, which is a serious privacy and security concern.

As to where to download them, it's a little harder. The official homepage only gives links to the very latest version, and apparently older ones aren't available there. That's about the only safe place one can rely to get any software, the official developer. Googling a bit more can reveal some other links to externally hosted copies here and there (mostly piracy-oriented websites). So far, I can't recommend getting any of those unless you're really want those very much.

The only reliable way I find right now is either to unwillingly accept the latest version or try to find a backup of the older installer that you know safe to use. As a future recommendation, *always have a backup of the installers of every software you use*, just in case something goes wrong and the official site no longer provides it, or as this is the case, the official has become much worse than previous versions.